# Getting tag version using semantic releases

Tags: gitlab-ci, semantic-release

I am using semantic release for versioning in my repo. In my Gitlab when i merge my branch with develop my tag increases according to the commit and it works fine.

I now want to get the current version to pass it to another stage of CI.

I followed  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566805/getting-next-tag-version-using-semantic-releases)

and I have this `.releaserc.yml` file:

```
plugins:
  - "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
  - "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
  - "@semantic-release/exec":
    - publishCmd: "echo \"VERSION=${nextRelease.version}\" >> version.env"
  - "@semantic-release/gitlab"
tagFormat:
  - ${version}
branches:
  - "develop"
```

and this is the gitlab CI stage that I would like to use to grab the current version and save it as artifact

```
fetch-semantic-version:
  
  image: node:20
  stage: fetch-version
  variables:
    GITLAB_TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN
  only:
    refs:
    - develop

  script:
    - npm install @semantic-release/gitlab @semantic-release/exec



    - npx semantic-release --dry-run --no-ci --branches develop > VERSION.txt
    - cat VERSION.txt 
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - VERSION.txt
    reports:
      dotenv: version.env # this will save the version.env file and apply all variables in the next stage
```

when I push a commit (using [conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) ) I get this:

> [7:10:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found git tag 1.1.2 associated with version 1.1.2 on branch develop
> [7:10:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found 29 commits since last release
> [7:10:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
> [7:10:42 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  There are no relevant changes, so no new version is released.

I this case, no new release, I would like to get `1.1.2`, in the case of a new release, the logs would be:

> [2:43:30 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "analyzeCommits"
> of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer" [2:43:30 PM]
> [semantic-release] › ℹ  The next release version is 1.1.2 [2:43:30 PM]
> [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "generateNotes" of plugin
> "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator" [2:43:30 PM]
> [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "generateNotes" of plugin
> "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator" [2:43:33 PM]
> [semantic-release] › ✔  Created tag 1.1.2

how to fix it in such a way I can get, previous, version found and next to be sure I pass the correct one to the next stage?